# find the button that submitted the form

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript:

```
  $('#new_campaign_update').on('submit', function(event) {
    debugger; 
  });
```

Is there a way I can find the button that submitted the form?

```
  <%= form.submit 'Publish', class: 'button button-large button-primary accent-black', title: 'Publish this update now' %>
```

That is the button I clicked in order to submit the form can I find it on the event or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can with the event's `currentTarget`:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input');

buttons.forEach(b => b.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.currentTarget);
  e.currentTarget.style = "background-color:blue;";
}));
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="a">
<input type="submit" id="b">
<input type="submit" id="c">
<input type="submit" id="d">
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a form with `id=new_campaign_update`, and inside you have a single button with a class `button-primary`, the button will be accessible by `$(this).find(".button-primary")`, so you will access it like this:

```js
$('#new_campaign_update').on('submit', function(event) {
    const $button = $(this).find(".button-primary");
});
```

`$(this)` inside jQuery callbacks refers to the element that fired the callback. Inside the element you find the button with `.find(".button-primary)"`

Alternatively, if you have many buttons in a single form, you can add an onclick handler to the buttons themselves like this:

```js
$('#new_campaign_update .button-primary').click(function() {
    const $button = $(this);
}
```